# PHP image not storing in db

Tags: php, mysql

So i have a form, that will upload a title and content to my DB. I also have a file upload which will upload images to my 'img' FOLDER but not into my database. Can anyone help with the code i have:

editreview.php

`````
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO reviews (name, content, image)
          VALUES('" . $_POST['name'] . "',
                 '" . $_POST['content'] . "',
                 '" . $_POST['image'] . "')";

  if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
   $errors= array();
   $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
   $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
   $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
   $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
   $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

   $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

   if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
      $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
   }

   if($file_size > 2097152){
      $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
   }


  if ($conn->query($sql) && empty($errors) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"img/".$file_name);
    header('location: index.php');
  } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }
  $conn->close();
  }
}
?> ````
review.php

````</main>

<h2>Leave a review</h2>
<form method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Name: <input type="text" name="name">

Comment: <textarea name="content" rows="5" cols="40"> </textarea>
<input type="file" name="image" />

<button>Add Review</button>


Anyone know why the image is not posting/storing into my DB yet my title and content are directly storing to the database. I find it strange that my image is also storing into my images folder but not the main Database.
`````

Comment: Why you used `$_POST['image']` in your `sql` query ?

Comment: Insert $_FILES['image'] in db

Comment: @Al-AminSarker well shouldnt this be the case as im posting the image too ?

Comment: Ah i changed it to $_FILES and it now stores in my DB as 'Array'

Comment: Change from `$_POST['image']` to `$_FILES['image']['name']`

Comment: @user15441718 - try $_FILES['image']['name']

Comment: awesome tried that and worked successfully :)

Comment: Use prepared statements. Doors are open for SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

The upload will only store the file on your webservers file system.

The location will be `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']`.

You already use `move_uploaded_file()` to move the temporary file to `'img/' . $file_name`.

What you want to do instead is:

1. Open the file located at `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']`.
2. Read its content.
3. Convert it to a format you like to story the data in.
4. And then write that data in the SQL statement.

For example:

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO reviews (name, content, image)
          VALUES('" . $_POST['name'] . "',
                 '" . $_POST['content'] . "',
                 '" . base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) . "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `$_POST['image']` in your `sql` query but need to use `$_FILES['image']['name']`. So, change your `sql` query with this code

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO reviews (name, content, image)
          VALUES('" . $_POST['name'] . "',
                 '" . $_POST['content'] . "',
                 '" . $_FILES['image']['name'] . "')";
```